# Sql Server, Is "Reorganize Files Before Releasing Unused Space" better or worse?

Tags: sql-server, performance, tuning

I could not find a satisfactory answer. I fully understand that "Shrink" will cause index defragmentation, and that can worsen performance.

But, is not this option to reduce defragmentation?

So, to activate this option, is it better or worse? Please do not increase my confusion. I ask you to give me a clear and simple answer: it is better, or, it is worse.

Then if you want, give me your explanation that I will gladly read and appreciate.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is the equivalent of shrinking. To prove it, check the box and click the Script button at the top to see the shrink commands that it produces.

Generally speaking, that’s a great learning tool too - whenever you want to learn what something in the UI does, try that script button.

Comment: Okay. Great suggestion. I did the script test and the result was that this checkbox only allows you to edit the "Maximum free space in files after shrinking" percentage and pass it to the DBCC SHRINKDATABASE function. Nothing else.

Therefore, a possible final answer might be:

**Not better, nor worse. It does not matter. It only serves to activate the editing of the percentage of free space after the shrink.**

Comment: What does `Reorganize files before releasing unused space` really mean?

Comment: @variable literally what I wrote in the answer above.

Comment: The word is `reorganize files`. Obviously this isn't the same as index reorganize, so I'm still trying to think what does reorganize file technically mean. Does it mean reorganize the file contents maybe.

Answer (score 7):

Contrary to the existing answer, this does make a change to the SQL other than allowing you to specify a size as can be seen in the two generated scripts below (at least on my version of Enterprise Manager - SQL Server 2017).

```
-- Checkbox Unchecked
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'My_DB' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY)

-- Reorganise Checkbox Checked
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'My_DB' , 48491)
```

For the unchecked option, `TRUNCATEONLY` is applied which prevents the SQL server from performing any data reorganising. This is great if you want to release some space quickly without having an immediate performance impact, however it can effect ongoing performance as the database will become fragmented.

> TRUNCATEONLY Releases all free space at the file's end to the
> operating system but does not perform any page movement inside the
> file. The data file is shrunk only to the last allocated extent.
> target_size is ignored if specified with TRUNCATEONLY.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

**TLDR;** (rewritten based upon comments):

- Reorganising can allow for additional space to be released rather than just releasing the free space allocated at the end of the database (only under certain circumstances is this beneficial).
- Reorganising can affect performance until the procedure is complete (as is warned when using the SSMS interface to do so)
- Reorganising will fragment your indexes, so rebuild them afterwards
- Reorganising can experience a short term performance impact while the database physically moves the data pages around.

Comment: Shrinking `WITH TRUNCATEONLY`  does not cause the database to be more 'fragmented'. Shrinking with data movement (without `TRUNCATEONLY`) will fragment your indexes. Checking the reorganize files box and as a result, shrinking the database file(s) will only impact the database negatively. The only positive side effect would be the reduced size, and that side effect is only positive if the file will not grow out again.

Comment: "...  is only positive if the file will not grow out again" No, if you intend to migrate the file to another system, say across the internet, the reduced size can make a big difference. This is always on a case by case basis.